# what is the alternative in Tanzu for https://console.run.pivotal.io/

Tags: cloud-foundry, cloudfoundry-uaa, pcfdev, cloudfoundry-java-client

I used to create org and space and deploy app to PCF using https://console.run.pivotal.io/
But as its end of life happened in Jan2021 , I am searching for any alternate UI in Tanzu .

If above is not possible , kindly help me on how to create org,space and deploy app using cf push after its migration to Tanzu.

Kindly help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Pivotal products are now under the Tanzu name but doesn't mean PWS has also moved to some domain, It's no longer available. You need to look to migrate to one of certified providers https://cloudfoundry.org/certified-platforms and few of them do offer free trials also..

Answer (score 0):

If you are deploying Tanzu Application Service on your own infrastructure or on a public cloud, the URL for the console is `https://apps.system_domain`, where `system_domain` is the system domain that you entered in Ops Manager when you configure the Tanzu Application Service tile (it's under the Network screen).